# How to place image over this table and make the position responsive

Tags: html, css

I have placed the image but it breaks when we resize the window. 
I want it in the center of the first column which is description below the email service.
I want it to remain in the center all the time.
I have given the td position relative and made the image absolute position. Its relative to the td................................

```css
* {
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    table{
        width: 100%;
       border: 1px solid #edf2fc;
       border-collapse: collapse;
       margin-top: 30px;
     }
 
     table th {
       padding: 11px 6px 11px 6px;
       word-break: break-all;
       background: #413fa4;
       color: #fff;
       text-align: center;
     }
 
     tr td {
       border: 1px solid #cbdaf1;
     }
 
     table tbody td {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 33px 0 33px 0;
      word-break: break-all;
      font-size: 18px;
     }
 
     tfoot tr td {
       padding-top: 4px;
       padding-bottom: 4px;
     }

     tfoot tr td:first-child{
       padding-right: 22px;
     }
     .gray {
         background-color: lightgray
     }
```

```html
 <table width="100%">
    <thead style="background-color: lightgray;">
      <tr>

        <th>Description</th>

        <th>Cost</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td style="position: relative">Email  Service
          <img style="position: absolute; left: 300px; top: 70px;" src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/paid-thank-you-grunge-rubber-260nw-564254104.jpg"width=130px;>
        </td>
        <td align="center">1400.00</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Subtotal</td>
            <td align="center">1635.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Tax</td>
            <td align="center">294.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Discount</td>
            <td align="center">294.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Total</td>
            <td align="center" class="gray">$ 1929.3</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the text and the image inside a div with a flex box property, and then you can center it as you like

```css
* {
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    table{
        width: 100%;
       border: 1px solid #edf2fc;
       border-collapse: collapse;
       margin-top: 30px;
     }
 
     table th {
       padding: 11px 6px 11px 6px;
       word-break: break-all;
       background: #413fa4;
       color: #fff;
       text-align: center;
     }
 
     tr td {
       border: 1px solid #cbdaf1;
     }
 
     table tbody td {
      text-align: center;
      padding: 33px 0 33px 0;
      word-break: break-all;
      font-size: 18px;
     }
 
     tfoot tr td {
       padding-top: 4px;
       padding-bottom: 4px;
     }

     tfoot tr td:first-child{
       padding-right: 22px;
     }
     .gray {
         background-color: lightgray
     }
     
     .flex-b {
      display:flex;
      align-items:center;
      justify-content:center;
     }
```

```html
<table width="100%">
    <thead style="background-color: lightgray;">
      <tr>

        <th>Description</th>

        <th>Cost</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="flex-b">
               <span>Email  Service</span>
              <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/paid-thank-you-grunge-rubber-260nw-564254104.jpg"width=130px;>       
          </div>
        </td>
        <td align="center">1400.00</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Subtotal</td>
            <td align="center">1635.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Tax</td>
            <td align="center">294.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Discount</td>
            <td align="center">294.3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right">Total</td>
            <td align="center" class="gray">$ 1929.3</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
```